# Force Install-Module to always install to user folders

Tags: powershell, module, installation

I want to force PowerShell to always install Modules into user space. Weirdly, Microsoft have a facility to force installation to System folders requiring Admin with `Install-Module <Name> -Scope AllUser` but do *not* have a way to force installation to user folders.

```
$ModulePath = "$(Split-Path $Profile)\Modules"   # Want all modules here.
$ModulePathTest = foreach ($i in ($env:PSModulePath).split(";")) { if ($i -like $ModulePath) { $True } }   # $ModulePathTest will be $true if $ModulePath is on the $env:PSModulePath
if ($ModulePathTest -eq $null) { <do stuff> }
```

So I got this far and now stuck. If I am logged on Admin, I think it installs by default to `C:\Program Files` and if as a normal user, it will go to `$ModulePath`.

• Is there a quick way to add $ModulePath to $env:PSModulePath (and permanently, so I think this means it must be pushed into the registry right? I do not see a PowerShell command that can *permanently* update an environment variable - if I am wrong, would be good to know)?

• Is there a way that someone can think of to make `Install-Module` *always* install into `$ModulePath` in the above (i.e. `C:\Users\<Username>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`)?

Comment: You could create a so called proxy function for `Install-Module`, call the original cmdlet inside it and _predefine_ the parameter `-Scope` with `CurrentUser`.

Comment: hmm, you are right, it looks like Microsoft added the -Scope CurrentUser switch at some point as I saw at least 3 pages saying that it is not possible. I guess I can do that. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know the CurrentUser scope always has been there. You should always read the *official* help including the examples for all cmdlets you're about to use to know how to use them. ;-)

Comment: ok Olaf, I will make sure to read *all* of the official help and then I'll be 80. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply set the preference globally.

> [About Parameters Default Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parameters_default_values?view=powershell-7)
>
> Short description Describes how to set custom default values for
>   cmdlet parameters and advanced functions.
>
> Long description The $PSDefaultParameterValues preference variable
>   lets you specify custom default values for any cmdlet or advanced
>   function. Cmdlets and advanced functions use the custom default value
>   unless you specify another value in the command.
>
> Syntax The $PSDefaultParameterValues variable is a hash table that
>   validates the format of keys as an object type of
>   System.Management.Automation.DefaultParameterDictionary. The hash
>   table contains Key/Value pairs. A Key is in the format
>   CmdletName:ParameterName. A Value is the DefaultValue or ScriptBlock
>   assigned to the key.
>
> The syntax of the $PSDefaultParameterValues preference variable is as
>   follows:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues=@{"CmdletName:ParameterName"="DefaultValue"}
$PSDefaultParameterValues=@{ "CmdletName:ParameterName"={{ScriptBlock}} }
$PSDefaultParameterValues["Disabled"]=$True | $False
```

[Using $PSDefaultParameterValues in PowerShell](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/12/11/using-psdefaultparametervalues-in-powershell/)

> Let’s say we want to make sure that we do not accidently stop any
>   processes using Stop-Process. We can force WhatIf to always be used
>   with Stop-Process to better protect ourselves:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add("Stop-Process:WhatIf",$True)
```

> So, for what you are after,  ...

[What’s in your PowerShell $PSDefaultParameterValues Preference Variable?](https://mikefrobbins.com/2019/08/01/whats-in-your-powershell-psdefaultparametervalues-preference-variable/)

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{
    'Out-Default:OutVariable' = 'LastResult'
    'Out-File:Encoding' = 'utf8'
    'Export-Csv:NoTypeInformation' = $true
    'ConvertTo-Csv:NoTypeInformation' = $true
    'Receive-Job:Keep' = $true
    'Install-Module:Scope' = 'CurrentUser'
    'Install-Module:AllowClobber' = $true
    'Install-Module:Force' = $true
    'Install-Module:SkipPublisherCheck' = $true
}
```